# Ruby 2.1.5 - GC tuning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, garbage-collection, garbage, ruby-2.1

I have Ruby 2.1.5 installed on my server and need to configure GC tuning variables for the best/optimum Ruby performance.

Following is the hardware/software information information:

- Memory - 7697604 KB (8GB)
- CPU - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz (2 Cores)
- Ruby - 2.1.5
- Rails - 3.2.18
- Passenger - 4.0.27

Based on this link (http://tmm1.net/ruby21-rgengc/), i found around ~ 476K long lived objects (using `GC.stat(:heap_live_slot)`), and so i allocated

`RUBY_GC_HEAP_INIT_SLOTS=500000`

But what about the rest of the variables (mentioned below). What should be  appropriate values for these variables ? What more (and how) should i analyze in my environment / server to find appropriate values for these variables ?

```
RUBY_GC_HEAP_FREE_SLOTS=?
RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR=?
RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_MAX_SLOTS=?
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=?
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT_MAX=?
RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT_GROWTH_FACTOR=?
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT=?
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT_MAX=?
RUBY_GC_OLDMALLOC_LIMIT_GROWTH_FACTOR=?
RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR=?
```

If any other information is required, let me know !

Answer (score 2):

> How do I assign those values?

Through env variables e.g.:

```
RAILS_ENV=production RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=90000000 bundle exec thin start
export RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=90000000
...
```

(If I'm misunderstanding the question and you actually mean "What could I assign those values?" [Have a loook here](https://meta.discourse.org/t/tuning-ruby-and-rails-for-discourse/4126/60) and [here](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc).)

Comment: By "How do" i meant, what should I analyze in my environment / server to find a suitable value for these variables. By the way, i'll make the modification in my question. And thanx for the links. Will have a look.